# Возникновение скролла в Chrome при установлении свойства height: 100%

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, прокрутка, height

Приветствую.
Имеется такая конструкция:

```css
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#rWall {
    text-align: right;
}
#rWall img {
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='rWall'>
        <img src='system/img/rWall.png' alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
```

При этом изображение пропорционально подстраивается по высоте окна, как и должно быть. Но появляется скроллбар из-за 5px полоски внизу. Например, высота окна 643px, тогда `div` будет иметь высоту 648px, а изображение  — 643px.

Собственно, в чем моя ошибка? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
overflow:  hidden;
```

Убирает полосы прокрутки.

Comment: Это скроет полосы прокрутки, но прокручивать страницу все равно можно будет - мне это не нужно.

Comment: я не понимаю вас. не хотите страницу прокручивать - добавьте это к html тегу. если не это надо, то поясните подробней.

Comment: Простите, Вы были совершенно правы. Допустил ошибку из-за чего не сработало overflow. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Бывает, всегда пожалуйста. На будущее: существуют еще два свойства про скроллы. overflow-x и overflow-y.